# Trying to permanently change screen refresh rate

Tags: release-juno

I've been scouring the Internet for help on the matter but nothing I've found has helped me (mostly because I'm unfamiliar with Xrandr and how to use it, but also because I thought answers to other questions were unclear). This is why I'm asking my own question, and I know nobody likes repeat questions, but I don't know what else to do at this point.

I've got Elementary OS 5.0 installed on a Dell Optiplex GX520, and I'm using a Dell E773c CRT display (because it's the best spare display I have). Its native resolution is 1280x1024, and its native refresh rate is 85Hz. Right now, it's running at 75Hz, and this causes weird graphical distortion on the display and it drives my eyes nuts, so I've been trying to get it back up to 85Hz.

From what I gathered online, Xrandr doesn't apply display settings across reboots (and I don't know how to apply those settings in Xrandr anyways) and I don't want to have to be changing the refresh rate every reboot.

Also, if you know of a control panel application that is a little more in-depth and advanced than the default Elementary OS settings application, I'd very much like to know about it. Can anyone help me out?